# select ID from table where (no, id) in (ID, >5000)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with id and no:

```
id   | no

A999 | 6000
A999 | 5000
A999 | 3000
A999 | 1000

B999 | 5000
B999 | 4000
B999 | 7000
B999 | 9000

C999 | 9000
C999 | 5000
C999 | 2000
C999 | 1000
```

From that I select for each id a limitting no (select id, max(now where ...), whit a result like:

```
id   | no
A999 | 5000
B999 | 7000
C999 | 2000
```

Now I can make this query, and it works fine:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE (no, id) 
IN (The select above)
```

It gives me 3 rows.

But what if I want to query rows with id from the select and no> no from the select
Something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE (no, >id) 
IN (The select above)
```

With this result:

```
id   | no

A999 | 6000
A999 | 5000

B999 | 7000
B999 | 9000

C999 | 2000
C999 | 1000
```

Could that be done?

BR Kresten

Comment: please edit the question and show the sample input table data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not like that.

I'll try to answer this, but it would be a lot easier if you showed your full query.

```
SELECT *
FROM table t
WHERE exists
    (select 1 from other_table o
     where t.no = o.no
       and t.id > o.id) 
;
```

If this doesn't give you the results you want, you'll need to show us more of your data and expected results.

Answer (score 0):

One method is `join`:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select id, max(no) where ...) tt
     on t.id = tt.id and t.no > tt.no;
```